# Why did they begin using the F-word in Season 7 (2017)?

Tags: dialogue, suits

In the US TV series *Suits*, I don't think they used the word "fuck" a single time in the first six seasons (2011–2016).

But in Season 7 (2017), they begin using it (perhaps once per episode). In Seasons 8 and 9, they use it more often (perhaps thrice per episode).

What's the reason for this? (In particular, was there maybe some legal reason for why they could begin using "fuck" in season 7?)

Comment: Just curious where you are? I think when it was first shown in the UK (on UKTV I think) it was sometimes quite obviously edited. However, the channel that has shown the last couple of seasons (Paramount?) is obviously not so bothered or it's on later or whatever.

Comment: Mayen they hope to win a Rory.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a good article that explains why shows in general have become more comfortable with the usage of that specific expletive.

*just a note, use of swear words in quotes have been censored, some people are not comfortable with them, and as censoring swear words did not alter the meaning of this article, I censored it for those not comfortable with them. Aside from that, it is a direct quote*

[use of f*** in shows](https://www.slashfilm.com/swearing-on-syfy-and-usa/)

As the article explains, it has more to do with the actual network and the advertisers those networks use than it does a specific show. It mentions several networks, including the network Suits is on, USA. In answer to your question about whether any sort of legality is involved, here is a direct quote:

> "Previously, swearing on SyFy and USA stuck to the guidelines laid out by the Federal Communications Commission, but as a basic cable channel, their Standards and Practices division was not actually beholden to follow those rules strictly. Instead, they answer to their advertisers, who traditionally don’t like it when things get controversial on television programming, and that includes salty language"

Here is another quote that explains why they have begun to use the word.

> "The only thing holding back basic cable networks from using what is considered to be more vulgar language is their advertisers. To keep things clean, they usually dip the audio of either the “f” or the “k” whenever “f***”*(quote altered for censorship*) is said in an episode. But according to Buzzfeed, USA and SyFy have worked that all out because their stance now is “when language — ‘f***’*(quote altered for censorship*) specifically — is deemed important to the style or plot of a show, Syfy and USA now allow it.” That means the episode gets slapped with a TV-MA rating so audiences know it’s intended for mature audiences only."

Comment: Comedy Central also allowed the F-word in their roast of Alec Baldwin.

Comment: The cited article says "fuck", not "f***". Why the censoring?

Comment: @xehpuk Some people aren't comfortable with the word, so I wanted to be considerate of those feelings, as censoring it would not affect the meaning/message of the article.

Comment: @katyp93 If you are going to alter a quote, then please indicate in the quote that you have altered it and exactly how/where it is altered. If you don't indicate the alterations, it's assumed that what you are quoting is *exactly* as you have displayed it, with the exception of formatting. Although, you should also try to stay close to any formatting used, particularly if the formatting is used to convey or help to convey information.

Comment: @Makyen No problem, makes sense. I edited my comment to explain that there is altering of the quotes as well as marked in the quotes where the alterations are.

Comment: SyFy in particular was always really obvious about this. On some of their  original shows, they'd just make up a drop-in replacement like *shtako* for *shit* or something just as bad. Supposedly it made it sound "alien" or "foreign" for more realism, but it always broke the illusion for me.

Comment: Years ago, Toronto's CITY television station was allowed to say "fuck, but not "mother fucker".  So they censored it as "M[eeep] fucker".